# Is this joke answer really an answer?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/190103/46732) on the [Bypass MAC address internet time filtering](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190102/bypass-mac-address-internet-time-filtering) question seems to be a joke answer, half-answering the question using specific terminology (re: *timing attack*, *side channel attack*). Obviously these are jargon-jokes. You can even see [one in the comments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190102/bypass-mac-address-internet-time-filtering#comment375332_190103).

I upvoted the answer and that comment because they're funny, but this obviously doesn't answer the question. The answer does link to MAC address spoofing which technically *does* answer the question, but then it basically becomes a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), which isn't ideal.

What should be done with this answer, if anything? It's in the Hot Network Questions, so it's just going to garner more attention from this point, so I think a quality assessment is a good idea.

Comment: For the record, the answer has since been reworked.

Comment: And the hilarious comment got deleted as well. Agh, my best joke on security.SE so far.

Comment: @alecxe see, I still see the comment and the answer on mobile... not sure that the answer was actually deleted...

Comment: @ChrisCirefice ah, it got improved and undeleted. Awesome! And awesome that they kept the comment as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please, just use the flag tool to notify moderators when you see non-answers or anything else flag-worthy.

And if something is not an answer, please don't upvote it.

I have deleted the post as it was not an answer, and have closed the question as it is off topic here.

You are right that HNQs can cause issues as votes happen quickly, and come from people who may be unfamiliar with the site scope, so flagging and voting early really helps prevent things like this.